# Verb or noun for - when I am not short of words but unable to speak lucidly

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

*A situation when I am not short of words but confused by the setting.
the situation does not let me speak properly/lucidly.* I kind of trip over my words.

> I don't know what to do. The silence was deafening. I finally
>   ___________ out. Sir, Can I meet you.

Comment: "I finally blurted out"

Comment: @Mitch, +1, and that's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural way to fill in that blank is:

> I finally *blurted* out.

Comment: Also, what can describe the speaker is 'inarticulate'.

Answer (score 7):

> I don't know what to do. The silence was deafening. I finally
>   ***stuttered*** *out*. Sir, Can I meet you.

Use the **verb** stutter when someone gets stuck on certain word sounds, either because she's speaking too quickly or eagerly.

**[To speak haltingly](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/stutter?family=stuttered)**

Usage examples-

> - So after she **stuttered** a bit, she said, “I’ve been thinking so much about Pussy Riot.” (Washington Post,May 5, 2015)
> - “Can you young brothers spare some change? I need to make a phone call,” he **stuttered**. (The Other Wes Moore: One Name, Two Fates)

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/stutter?family=stuttered))

Answer (score 5):

I'd use ***[utter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/utter)***:

> - To articulate (words); pronounce or speak: uttered "yes." (AHD)

- I finally uttered (out). "Sir, Can I meet you."

Comment: The definition you've provided in no way connotes confusion... I'm not sure how this fits.

Comment: @DaveMagner - I don't see the *"confusion connotation*" you are hinting at, not in the meaning of the term.

Answer (score 4):

Verb and Noun -

Someone who **falters is unsteady, wobbly, or unsure**.

> You might falter while reciting a poem if you forget some of the
>   lines, or falter crossing a rickety rope bridge when fear gets the
>   most of you.

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/falter))

Answer (score 2):

We often use the word "managed" to convey the idea that we're having some sort of difficulty doing  something.

**I finally *managed to ask*, "Sir, can I meet you?"**

Answer (score 0):

> I finally **collected my thoughts**, "Sir, can I meet you?"

Meets the confusion requirement I think:

> To collect one's thoughts means to take time for his/herself after a
>   particularly disturbing event, and to get his/her mind back in order.

(urbandictionary.com)

or with a bit of artistic license:

> I finally **untied my tongue**, "Sir, can I meet you?"

But only really if the cause of the pause was shyness/embarrassment:

> **tongue-tied** adjective
>   1. too shy or embarrassed to speak. "Barbara was tongue-tied in the presence of her parents"

(Google)